# Determining whether an input number is negative or positive in javascript

Tags: javascript

If given a javascript that took a number as input from the user and determined whether the number was negative or positive, in what situation would u throw an exception?

Comment: This looks like homework. Here's something to help you: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Operators#Comparison_operators

Comment: your question is unclear. what is it that you want to do? positive or negative, or validate the input?

Comment: its a javascript program that determines if the user input is negative or positive im asking when there will be a time where id have to throw in an exception

Comment: I would throw an exception if you accept any values other than integers

Comment: @karthikr—so `isPosOrNeg(1.5)` should throw an error?

Answer (score 2):

You should throw exceptions in *exceptional* situations. If you're accepting input of a number (either positive or negative), then something that doesn't fit the criteria, like say a string or an object, should be considered exceptional.

**Example:**

```
// Assume the variable 'input' contains the value given by user...
if(typeof input != "number") {
    throw "Input is not number!"
}
else {
    // ... handle input normally here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the code.

An obvious function is:

```
function isPosOrNeg(x) {
  return x < 0? 'negative' : 'positive';
}
```

it's very difficult to see that throwing an exception. There might be one if `x` is an unresolvable reference, but it isn't (it's a formal parameter so effectively a declared variable).

The [<](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.1) operator uses the [abstract relational comparison algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5), which doesn't throw errors, though it might return `undefined` depending on the values provided.

I wouldn't throw an error at all, since `undefined` is a perfectly reasonable response that the caller can deal with.

If you want to test the parameters, then perhaps:

```
function isPosOrNeg(x) {

  if ( isNaN(Number(x))) {
    // throw an error
  }

  return x < 0? 'negative' : 'positive';
}
```

so that `isPosOrNeg('foo')` throws an error but `isPosOrNeg('5')` does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
   var inp="your input value";
   if(isNaN(inp)){
      return "Not a number";
    } else {
      if( inp > 0 ) {
          return 'positive number';
       } else if( inp < 0 ) {
          return 'negative number';
       } else {
          return 'number is zero';
       }
    }
```